# How can I implement onTouch function android?

Tags: android, gesture

Hi I want to create aplication which loads large image, and simple gesture I can move across it. I have to image printed out but I can not implement onTouch so it remains stationary. Any help apreseated. Thanks

My code for drawing out the picture:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          super.onDraw(canvas);
                   Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            // make the entire canvas white
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setPathEffect(null);
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);


            for (int i=1; i < 100; i++){
                canvas.drawLine(0, i*1 , 600, i*20, paint);
                canvas.drawLine(i*1 ,0, i*20, 600, paint);      
            }
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far?  Show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your view, you need to create the "OnTouchListener" which should look something like this:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListnener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
        switch(e.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //and code will go here for putting the finger on the screen
```

I would have a look at [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and looking at the various levels.  You'll want to pay attention to how it can pack several bits of movement information into one `MotionEvent.`

Comment: I implement this metod  this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
          switch(e.getAction()){
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              x++;
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
             // move the balls the same as the finger
                 x = x-25;
                 y = y-25; 
                 break;
          }
          return true;
      }//but for this bracet it trows me an error why
   }

Comment: @suter perhaps your "x" and "y" are getting outside the bounds of the screen?

Answer (score 6):

As you're already writing a custom view, instead of setting a listener, you might want to incorporate a `GestureDetector` and listener inside your view, and above all avoid the `switch(e.getAction())` thing, because `OnGestureListener` is on a higher level and will provide you with event already detected as a gesture (scroll, fling, long press...).

See an example [here](http://www.anddev.org/gesturedetector_and_gesturedetectorongesturelistener-t3204.html).

Comment: I like that.  Perhaps this is much better suited to what he's trying to accomplish.