# Help with making objects touchable on Android using canvas

Tags: android, canvas, touch

I'm trying to create a simple Pegs game. I have drawn the 15-hole board using canvas. I have been programming a while, but games are new to me and I'm stuck on what to do when it comes to handling the pegs. I want to only use the touch screen, but it seems like it is really difficult to touch the pegs and actually select them individually. I plan on just drawing everything programmatically. What is best way on handling this? Using buttons as place holders and changing the button image? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To be very brief, you have to keep track of the things you draw on the canvas.

I wrote some tutorials for [making and moving selectable shapes on the canvas](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes). They should help a lot.

On android it might be a little different than using mousedown, but it should give you a very good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but you might want to write your own `onTouch()`function. Check [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135740/how-can-i-implement-ontouch-function-android) out