# Develop a view like a designer of simple shapes (Square and circle) in android

Tags: android, drawing, android-custom-view

Hello I've beens struggling with this for a while, trying to build kind of a designer where I can put some shapes in it by tapping (or dragging them), the problem is that I've try to understand the [Touch gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html) they talk about viewport, scrolling and dragging to create a chart, nevertheless I was aiming for something more like a map design, something like this:

[image]

So far I've been able to do the basic like when you touch it will draw a circle and been able to scale, but I am still not understanding the whole viewport, content, and OverScroller combination. Could you point me out some advices? Has anyone done this? any tutorial or example where it can be explained in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to change a square bitmap to circular bitmap

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      int targetWidth = 50;
      int targetHeight = 50;
      Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
                                targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
      Path path = new Path();
      path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
      ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
      (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
              Path.Direction.CCW);

                    canvas.clipPath(path);
      Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
      canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
                                    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
        sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
                                    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
        targetHeight), null);
      return targetBitmap;
     }
```

Also look at these method of `Path` class

```
path.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle);
path.addOval(oval, dir);
path.arcTo(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your questions all you need is a custom `View` to draw objects in `Canvas`. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html%20%22%22). A simple example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_view);
   }
}

public class MyView extends SurfaceView{

    public MyView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       // Draw here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event){
       // Touch events here
       return true;
    }
}
```

And in your layout `XML`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.your.package.MyView
        android:id="@+id/joystickView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

   <!-- Right side panel with buttons -->
   <Button ... />

   <Button ... />

   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

So now you have a custom `View` in your `Activity` and you can draw anything you want with `Canvas` and get the user touch coordinates in the `onTouch()` event. Read about `onTouch()` in SO or [here](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html%20%22%22) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135740/how-can-i-implement-ontouch-function-android%20%22%22).

You can also read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html%20%22%22) about gestures, basically `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is the first time you touch the screen here you can get the coordinates for the initial point where you draw the circle for example. Then `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is when you are dragging you finger and you can get the coordinates so you can drag whatever you draw before. When dragging use `motionEvent.getRawX()` and `motionEvent.getRawY()` instead of `motionEvent.getX()` and `motionEvent.getY()` for a smooth dragging.

Now according to where the user touches the screen you can draw anything you want in that coordinates. To create a rightpanel as in your image you can add buttons in the `Activity` layout which is also holding your custom `View`, so the left side of your `Activity` is the custom `View` where you draw everything and the left side are buttons to select what to draw for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is an abstraction. See it like this:
Your world is the map you are drawing on.
Only parts of it are visible, the parts that are within your view port, a rectangle.
When Scrolling, you are moving your view port to other parts of your map, which may have been
 insivible before. 
If you imagine looking at a world map with a  small light, you only see the parts that are lightened. 
If you imagine putting a coordinate system on a world map, this would mean you see only a 
rectangle from (0,0) - (10,10), e.g., if your lense would be of size 10.
Moving your lense is like moving your viewport.
So you got to have a resolution from your real map (which could be greated than your display's size)
 to the size which is displayed and the part of the map which becomes visible on scroll.
 If you store your coordinates for the pictures/images/circles that you are drawing,
 you can calculate easily which objects are visible and where they got do be displayed. 
Say that your display is of size 800x400, your maps size is internally 8000x4000, 
you have a rectangle 100X100 with the left bottom corner at 0,0 and another one at -200,0.
 
When your viewport is at 0,0 you can see the first rectangle.
When scrolling to the left, you are not moving your map but your viewport.
When your viewport has been moved to 50,0 , you can see half of the rectangle.
This calculation can be done via various mathematical transformations on vectors using 
matrices and can become rather complex 
 but are well known.
If you take a look at the OpenGL ES - tutorial, you can see more about the concept of viewports (they are similar to the camera - object).
I hope, this could help a little bit.